# Subtraction method to solve permutation problem with multiple conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A library contains 4 identical copies of book A, 2 identical copies of book B and 5 identical copies of book C. These 11 books are arranged on a shelf in a library.

Calculate the number of different arrangements if all the books A are next to each other and none of the books B are next to each other.

The answer booklet for this question firsts starts by calculating the arrangements if all of the books A are together(8!/(2!*5!=168)) and then calculating the arrangements if both Books A and B are together(7!/5!=42). Then, finally subtracting them to get 126 as the answer. However,I don't get the idea behind the subtraction. How does it lead to the result we need. A visual representation of the conditions asked using something like a Venn diagram would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please reproduce the **exact** wording of the answer booklet, and also edit in what efforts you have made, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are just $2$ B-books, them being together is the complement for no B-books being together. That why the subtraction. The A-book condition just tags along. Actually, you can think that there is just one A-book and forget about the A-book condition (glue them together and you have just one object).